# Open MS Office templates with Firefox?

Tags: microsoft-office-2007, templates, firefox

I've a problem with Firefox or MS Office maybe both of them. Our firm has an Intranet and publishes some documents via Intra.

MS Office 2007 is used to create document templates and stored as "file://depo/ISO9001/*****/Form/*****_Form.xlt, _Form.dot" in the server. Unfortunately Firefox can't open these templates or downloads over Intra.

Is there any solution to this issue? I don't want to use Firefox after IE after Firefox.

Many thanks and any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're linking to a file in a UNC path (e.g., \servername\share\file.ext), you will need to specify the path like this:

> file://///servername/share/file.ext

Yes, those are 5 slashes.

More info: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Firefox_:_Issues_:_Links_to_Local_Pages_Don%27t_Work

Comment: Must this change  be done in Intra web page or I can do it by myself?

Answer (score 0):

A `.xlt` file is an Excel template and a `.dot` is a Word template. These are templates for new documents in the respective programs.

To open the files as web pages for reading in Firefox, you need to select File -> Save as -> Web page.